The named parameter 'pickerTitle' is required, but there's no corresponding argument
I am using bottom_picker and the named parameter 'title' isn't defined. how can i correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'title'.
What is the wrong ?

how can i do it. what i have to change in script ?

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

If you click on the link you provided and then go to the tab Changelog, you will find that title was deprecated and has been removed in bottom_picker version 2.7.0.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to use the pickerTitle property which would take a Text widget that would contain the title, for example:
BottomPicker.dateTime(
    pickerTitle: Text(
        'Set the event exact time and date',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 15,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      onSubmit: (date) {
        print(date);
      },
      onClose: () {
        print('Picker closed');
      },
      minDateTime: DateTime(2021, 5, 1),
      maxDateTime: DateTime(2021, 8, 2),
      initialDateTime: DateTime(2021, 5, 1),
      gradientColors: [
        Color(0xfffdcbf1),
        Color(0xffe6dee9),
      ],
).show(context);

For reference: https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_picker
